# Extract sub-elements from XPATH Fetch Page pipe

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I'm hoping to convert the content of 3 adjacent `TD` elements in a `TR` using Yahoo Pipes to a comma-delimited list of values.  Source: [Epic Systems Hospitals](http://epic.usergroup.healthitsocial.com/page/epic-hospitals).

HTML snippet:

...

```
<table width="623" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr height="20">
        <td width="425" height="20">Institution 0</td>
        <td width="134">Minneapolis</td>
        <td width="64">MN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height="20">
        <td height="20">Institution 1</td>
        <td>Philadelphia</td>
        <td>PA</td>
      </tr>
```

...

I've used the "XPath fetch page" source to correctly isolate the `TR` elements using an XPATH=`//tr[@height='20']`.

I'm having difficulty getting the `TD` elements, however.  It's not obvious to me which component I should be using, so I chose a Sub-element with the '[special variable substitution](http://pipes.yqlblog.net/2012/04/24/new-module-xpath-fetch-page/)' syntax.  Unfortunately, `${td.0.content}` doesn't work.

What am I not understanding?

** edit **

My goal is to create an XML stream that resembles:

```
<institutions>
  <institution name='Institution 0' city='Minneapolis' region='MN'/>
  <institution name='Institution 1' city='Philadelphia' region='PA'/>
  ...
<institutions/>
```

[image]

Comment: From my understanding the `xfetch` page emits `html5` contents (as you have selected that option) or it can emit `strings`. `Sub-element` module helps in getting the data from the hierarchy which can be in form of XML or RSS feeds.

Comment: From the page that I reference: "Currently this module will extract the page and fix malformed tags using Tidy. "  Doesn't this suggest that the document has been converted to XHTML?

Answer (score 3):

If you always have 3 td cells, you could use a `Loop` operator with a `String Builder` inside, and build a string by concatenating `item.td.0`, `item.td.1`, `item.td.2`.

I created an example of this for you here:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=3d24486f7c6e8413dc6252ef37c2f086

Comment: It seems that values can be inserted into the HTML stream, but the stream can't be re-written.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so too. In any case, be careful, Yahoo Pipes is quite buggy, so don't expect consistent and logical behavior.